# Simplifying design for the filters on Amazon QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a list of data with columns stating whether the data qualifies for the relevant tags. The problem is some instances the data qualify for more than one tag.

Is there a way to design a filter on QuickSight that would allow me to show this in a clear manner?

For example, if the data looks like this:

```
Data         Category_tag       

Lemon        Fruit              
Melon        Fruit              
Watermelon   Fruit              
Tomato       Fruit & Vegetable  
Onion        Vegetable          
Okra         Fruit & Vegetable  
Potato       Vegetable
```

I would want the Filter to be given two choices 'Fruit' and 'Vegetable' which would show all items that qualify, not just one with the exact match.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a parameter `FruitVeg`, with a parameter control list with `{Fruit,Vegetable}`and a calculated filed `Filtered_data`

```
ifelse(locate({Category_tag},{FruitVeg})>0,{Data},null)
```